# Tkinter: Animated Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to make a canvas in Tkinter which should move after every one second.
I have written this code.

```
import time
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x800')
c = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
c.config(bg='#00f')
c.place(x=0)

y = 0
while True:
    print(y)
    c.place(x=y)
    y -= 50
    if y < -500:
        break
    time.sleep(1)
root.mainloop()
```

Here, I used **While Loop** to make animation in which after every 1 second, **A Blue Canvas** will move to **-ve x-axis**.

It is moving as I want but the window is appearing after animation **(Because I used root.mainloop() after While Loop)** and I can't use **root.mainloop()** before **While Loop** because it will give the error.

Is there any other way that the animation should run only after the creation of window?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter+animation

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding `mainloop()` essentially keeps the app/widget rendering.
All that `mainloop()` actually does is this

```
while True:
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
```

So this means that the only rendering in your program is done by the `root.mainloop()` call right at the end, so you would simply need to use what is inside the `mainloop()` function and put it inside your *own* main loop.

For example:

```
while True:
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    print(y)
    c.place(x=y)
    y -= 50
    if y < -500:
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

And then if you wanted the application to stop rendering after y went below -500, then just remove the `root.mainloop()` call at the bottom.

Comment: That's not entirely true. `update` is a superset of `update_idletasks`. You don't need to call them both, just calling `update` will do. Also, every time you sleep in that loop the GUI will become unresponsive. With this solution your GUI will be responsive for a few milliseconds, freeze for a full second, be responsive for a few milliseconds, ...